# Declaring an object type in an if statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to declare a variable inside an if statement. If the result of a query is YES then the object will be of one type, otherwise it will be of another type. A bit like this...

```
if (YES) {
          ObjectTypeA *object = [[ObjectTypeA] alloc] init];
}

else {
      ObjectTypeB *object = [[ObjectTypeB] alloc] init];
}
```

Once that's done I want to use object with the same methods no matter what type it is. I tried declaring object as an id before the if statement but get an error: member reference type 'struct objc_object *' is a pointer; maybe you meant to use '->'?

I also tried declaring both to be separate objects outside the if and then make the pointer point to whichever it was once I knew. That wouldn't work either.

I know that the compiler is trying to protect me from myself by doing this but in this circumstance I need a way round it please.

Thanks.

Comment: Worked around this problem by breaking out the detection, i.e. YES or NO into separate method. Then declaring objects in each method called depending on the YES or NO.

Comment: Thanks for all who took the time to leave an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common pattern for this problem in Cocoa/Cocoa Touch is to define a protocol.

A protocol is a collection of methods that can be implemented by any object.

If you make ClassA and ClassB conform to a protocol containing the methods you need them to respond to then you don't need to worry about which type of object you get.

The idea is "if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then it's probably a duck".

You can use dynamic typing and create your objects depending on the outcome of your query, but ensure that the resulting object conforms to a particular protocol, like so:

```
id <MyProtocol> myObject;

if (YES)
    myObject = [[ClassA alloc] init];
else
    myObject = [[ClassB alloc] init];

[myObject myMethod];
[myObject release];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code should work well:

```
id obj = nil;

if (YES) {
   obj = [[ObjectTypeA] alloc] init];
} else {
   obj = [[ObjectTypeB] alloc] init];
}

[obj performSelector:@selector(YOUR_METHOD) withObject:YOUR_OBJECT];
```

Comment: It might be useful to mention the other mistake in the questioner's code, in that the variables defined inside the the if/else will be out of scope outside the if/else.

Comment: I am not sure but the explanation says something about declaring outside : " also tried declaring both to be separate objects outside the if and then make the pointer point to whichever it was once I knew. That wouldn't work either." I don't really get it so I write again

Comment: You could call the method directly, in this case `the performSelector:` is not neccessary.

Comment: I tried declaring them outside as suggested here but had an error telling me member reference type 'struct objc_object *' is a pointer; maybe you meant to use '->'?. This happened anyplace I tried to call a method on object.

Comment: Tried this one and it still displays the error I mention above when I try and call methods based on the object.

Comment: what, are you sure? It is impossible, what object type are you trying to call? Or are you calling an instance variable/property? Please give me more codes for the method as well as both class A and B declaration

Comment: And don't use the name "object" for the variable name, please

Answer (score 0):

You want dynamic typing :)

The way around this is to declare a third object that both of these inherit from

OR

You could use the adapter pattern and create an object that accepts both of these objects as a member and then wrap the functions you wish to call into that object

good luck!

--> These are genral OO solutions; I'm not a Objective-C developer